# Leaks shows a leak when allocating a UILabel, [NSNotificationCenter addObserver], appears to be "UIAccessibilityButtonShapesChangedNotification"

Tags: memory-leaks, uikit, uilabel, nsnotificationcenter

We first became curious when our largest leaks were from `NSNotification addObserver` frames,

[image]

If you look at the Stack Trace, it looks like it's happening when we initialize a UILabel.
[image]

Here is our relevant code:

```
final class TileView: UIView {
  fileprivate let digitLabel        = UILabel()
  fileprivate let mainLineView      = UIView()
  fileprivate let secondaryLineView = UIView()
```

...

```
required init(builder: FlapViewBuilder, position: Position) {
    self.cornerRadii = CGSize(width: builder.cornerRadius, height: builder.cornerRadius)
    self.position    = position

    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    setupViewsWithBuilder(builder)
}
```

I set a symbolic breakpoint at for `addObserver`, and caught the frame that was leaking.  I checked out the registers:

```
(lldb) register read
General Purpose Registers:
        x0 = 0x0000000283c937e0
        x1 = 0x00000001df7310a8  @"UIAccessibilityButtonShapesChangedNotification"
        x2 = 0x00000001d8b763e8  @"kCFNotificationAnyObject"
        x3 = 0x0000000000000400
        x4 = 0x0000000108e1dcb0
        x5 = 0x0000000000000000
        x6 = 0x000000016d72e4a0
        x7 = 0x0000000000000000
        x8 = 0x00000001a9493e74  Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2
        x9 = 0x00000001d8d0e2b0  Foundation`__block_descriptor_48_e8_v16@?0@8l
       x10 = 0x000000010b814800
       x11 = 0x0000013f000001ff
       x12 = 0x000000010b8154a0
       x13 = 0x000001a1e23c6b97 (0x00000001e23c6b97) (void *)0x000001e23c738800
       x14 = 0x000000000000000f
       x15 = 0x00000001e238c95a  __CFCharToUniCharTable
       x16 = 0x00000001e23c6b90  (void *)0x000001a1e23c6bb9
       x17 = 0x00000001a7c0b250  libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject class]
       x18 = 0x0000000000000000
       x19 = 0x0000000108e1dcb0
       x20 = 0x00000001d5615e89  "_accessibilityButtonShapesChangedNotification:"
       x21 = 0x00000001df7310a8  @"UIAccessibilityButtonShapesChangedNotification"
       x22 = 0x0000000000000000
       x23 = 0x0000000283396370
       x24 = 0xfffffffef71e234f
       x25 = 0x0000000102e91000  "setShouldRasterize:"
       x26 = 0x0000000ffffffff8
       x27 = 0x00000001027c2054  Sideline`protocol witness for Sideline.SplitflapDelegate.splitflap(_: Sideline.Splitflap, builderForFlapAtIndex: Swift.Int) -> Sideline.FlapViewBuilder in conformance Sideline.SplitflapView : Sideline.SplitflapDelegate in Sideline at <compiler-generated>
       x28 = 0x000000010cc878d0
        fp = 0x000000016d72e500
        lr = 0x00000001a938d1a8  Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:] + 256
        sp = 0x000000016d72e4a0
        pc = 0x00000001a938d224  Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:] + 380
      cpsr = 0x60000000
```

Saw this: "UIAccessibilityButtonShapesChangedNotification"

Is there anything we can do about this?
Maybe just a bug with UILabel/UIKit?
Or I'm misinterpreting the results of the Leaks report?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue in Xcode 12.3. Did you ever find a solution...?

Comment: Hm unfortunately it was a while ago, so I don't recall :\ I think we ended up just removing that from the UI